# instagram /media/recent api only fetch lastone image

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, count, instagram

I want to get recent 10 images from Instagram, but it always getting me only last upload image.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count=10

Comment: Hello, the link you posted.. only works for the authenticated user.. `.../self/...` maybe a better place to start would be the documentation for the API?

Answer (score 1):

there is an api function for customizing the Instagram feed's using instafeed.min.js

Below is an example snippet with limit of 10 feeds.

```js
  var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: '212*****',
  accessToken: '21258593*********************************',
  limit: '10',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  links: true,
  resolution: 'low_resolution',
});
```